# How do undo a merge or move my master branch forward?

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches:

master
AddEmailPickUpService

I merged master into AddEMailService a couple of commits ago.  I should have merged AddEmailService into master.  How do I bring master up to where AddEmailService is ?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just merge back `AddEmailService` into `master`? It will leave your branch `AddEmailService` in the altered state though.

Comment: I'll try that.  That would be fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merge the branch into `master`:

```
> git checkout master
> git merge AddEmailPickUpService
```

It should do a fast-forward.